# Page turn empty when POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit

I have 2 php files:

**index.php**

```
<?php
@ini_set('default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1');
echo '<form method=post action="aplicacao.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="Joaquim"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="permissoes" value="administrador"/>';
echo '<input style="margin-left: 1150px; cursor=pointer;" type="submit" name="autorizado" value="Aplicação - Administração"></form>';
echo '<hr>';
echo '<form method=post action="aplicacao.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="username" value="Joaquim"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="permissoes" value="vendedor"/>';
echo '<input style="margin-left: 1150px; cursor=pointer;" type="submit" name="autorizado" value="Aplicação - Vendedor"></form>';
?>
```

**aplicacao.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['autorizado']))
{
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'administrador')
    {
        //something here
    }
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'vendedor')
    {
        //and something here
    }
}
?>
```

Then, when I submit POST, `aplicacao.php` turns white.

I know why, *but I don't know how to solve.*

Some help would be appreciated.

Greetings!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to not clear input fields in php form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345312/how-to-not-clear-input-fields-in-php-form)

Comment: Please tell us why? You have left so much out of the `aplicacao.php` I can only guess

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return to your index.php page, use the php header function to redirect:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['autorizado']))
{
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'administrador')
    {
        //something here
    }
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'vendedor')
    {
        //and something here
    }
}

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: I want to stay at aplicacao.php after POST

Comment: You can add content to the aplicacao.php page (like you did on index.php, use echo).

Comment: I have content: inputs text and submit button

Comment: Ow, so you want your index.php in your aplicacao.php page? You can use 'include' for this. Put `include 'index.php';` instead of the header function

Comment: I don't wanna go to index.php. I wan't to stay at aplicacao.php after POST

Comment: That's what include does... It includes your index.php file in aplicacao.php. [read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: I don't want to include index.php in aplicacao.php.

Comment: You want informationfrom index.php but you don't want to include it? You can copy the echo statements ... [or set the form action to "" and handle the POST-request on the index page (or include the aplicacao.php in your index page).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333901/php-form-on-submit-stay-on-same-page) . Or send the form using Ajax...

Answer (score -1):

What do you expect to see on the aplicacao.php page?
If you want to see the same form, you need to create routing and .htaccess with something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|phg|jpg|css)$ index.php
```

Comment: In aplicacao.php are some input text and a submit button

Comment: but your code is working, just write something where you want to see input text and the submit
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['autorizado']))
{
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'administrador')
    {
        echo "<form><input name="first" type="text" value="" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></form>"
    }
    if($_POST['permissoes'] == 'vendedor')
    {
       echo "<form><input name="second" type="text" value="" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></form>";
    }
}

?>

Comment: I wan't to stay at aplicacao.php after POST